# how can I make set of accumulatively increasing integers in R?

Tags: r, sequence, seq

How can I make set of accumulatively increasing integers in R?
What I want to make is a vector like

```
1  1  2  1  2  3  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  6  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 .
```

So I made it by

```
c(1,1,2,1:3,1:4,1:5,1:6,1:7,1:8,1:9,1:10)
```

Is there much simpler way than this? 
(I tried `1:(1:10)` <- this way but it doesn't work at all.)

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sequence`

```
sequence(1:10)
#[1]  1  1  2  1  2  3  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  5 .....
```